# Is my reputation 102 or 103?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Is my reputation 102 or 103?  My reputation tab seems unsure.

```
 103 reputation

 summary answers questions tags badges favorites bounties reputation activity responses votes
 103 Reputation

 graph time post

 102    today
 +100   1 hour ago  assoc   Association Bonus
 +2     1 hour ago  edit    What's the difference between “center” and “centre”?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reputation is 103. Every user starts out with 1 reputation that you get for free :)  The tab says you've *gained* 102 additional reputation today. So 102 + 1 is 103.

Comment: Of course!  You can see the edge case - I've just signed up, so there's only one day to show, otherwise it would be obvious.  And there's no + on the gain of 102, unlike the individual entries.